# Finding minimum paths in Graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

A Canadian postman, rather than returning to the post office $(p)$ after delivering
mail along every street in town, wishes to return straight home $(h)$.
Let $G$ be a connected graph and $p , h $ belongs to $ V (G)$. We define a postman $(p, h)$-walk
in $G$ to be a $(p, h)$-walk in $G$ that traverses each edge of $G$ at least once. If $G$ is a
weighted graph, then a minimum postman $(p, h)$-walk is a postman $(p, h)$-walk
of minimum total weight.
Could anyone explain in words (not pseudocode) that how  would  I find an optimal postman $(p, h)$-
walk in a weighted connected graph $G$ with given vertices $p$ and $h$ (where p ̸= h)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea:

You want to augment your graph by pretending it has extra edges so that you have an Eulerian Trail (a walk which uses every edge exactly one and starts and ends at different locations) from p to h. That means you want p and h to have odd degree and the rest of the vertices to have even degree.

So you look at the set of vertices which need to be "fixed", that is, the vertices that do not have the appropriate degree. Compute the lengths of the shortest paths between each pair of vertices in this set (for every pair, you need to know the shortest distance between the two vertices).

Now that you have you shortest path lengths, you need to consider all possible matchings of these vertices (that is, all possible ways to break the vertices up into pairs), and you pick the way which minimizes the total cost of the shortest path within each pair (so, when you look at the matching {a,b},{c,d}, the total you calculate is the length of the shortest path from a to b added to the length of the shortest path from c to d).

Once you have your matching, you pretend like you graph has an extra edge for each of these pairs (so, in the above example, you would add edge {a,b} and edge {c,d} with the weight of the edge being the length of the shortest path between the two vertices).

Now, you are pretty much done! All you need to do is find an Eulerian trail from p to h, and every time you use one of our pretend edges, you traverse the shortest path between the two vertices instead of the pretend edge.

Additionally, if you just want to find the cost of your walk, you can just add up the weights of all of the edges (including the pretend edges).